# Deno - Secure web sockets fails to connect but normal web sockets work

Tags: javascript, typescript, websocket, deno

I can't seem to connect to a wss server in deno. When I do create a wss socket, the readystate never gets set to open. However, ws works for some reason. Is this a bug or am I dumb?

```js
const websocket = new WebSocket("wss://echo.websocket.org");
websocket.addEventListener('open', (event:any) => {
    console.log(event)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer:

The website I used had an old certificate and doesn't meet up to rustls standards. If I listened to the error, I would have saw this error.